# How to prevent menu from closing when losing mouse focus?

Tags: html, css

I built a nice drop down menu using examples I had found on the web but my manager has run into the issue that the menu can be hard to use at times because if the mouse falls off of the menu it closes. I've read a few examples on how to get around it [here](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/), but my issue is that I can't get these solutions to work with my code.

Can someone give me a few pointers? My CSS code and a html example is included below:

```css
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: "charles modern"
}
#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align:center;
}
#cssmenu .padding{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 78;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: none !important;
}
/* Padding amount for first-level dropdown */
#cssmenu > li > .submenu > .padding{
  width: 400%;
  left: -30%;
  height: 160%;
}

#cssmenu .buffer{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 100%;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none !important;
}

#cssmenu .shadow{
  display: none !important;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #00A0DF;
  display: block;
  font-family: "charles modern", "charles modern light", Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:99999;

}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #047aea;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  font-size:150%;
  font-style: bold;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #00A0DF;
  color: white;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  color: black;
  font-syle: bold;
  font-size: 105%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #00A0DF;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #00A0DF;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='active has-sub'><center>Image 1</center></a>
  <ul>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Add New Item</span></a></li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>View Item</span></a></li>
    <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>Item With Sub-Items:</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>User 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>User 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <li class='active has-sub'><center>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Image 2</center></a>
<ul>
  <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Add New Item</span></a></li>
  <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>View Item</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle or something? are you just trying to get it to stay open a bit before going to the next menu item?

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated, use CSS instead. Also you have uninitialized `<a>` tags (you have only `</a>`). Also you have unclosed `<li>` tags (which might work... but just to make sure)

Comment: @Carine - jfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/64k5bLr5/). Yes, I'd like the menu to stay open either for a few seconds, or until a user has clicked off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Now using a different (simpler) method involving borders and container divs. Just change the color of the `border` property of `.level-2-menu, .level-3-menu` from `red` to `transparent` in your actual code. The only issue is the level 3 menu blocking the bottom right corner of the previous level 2 item.

[new jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7xhcr3h/2/)

---

It sounds like what you need is some area around each menu where you can be off the visible menu but still keep the menu open. Here is some code to demonstrate the concept. You should be able to adapt the concept into your code and style it however you like.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7xhcr3h/1/)

The `background-color: red` is just to make the extra hover area visible for demonstration purposes.

HTML:

```
<div class="cssmenu">
  <ul class="level-1-menu">
    <li class="level-1-item">
      <a href="#">Level 1 Item 1</a>
      <ul class="level-2-menu">
        <li class="level-2-item"><a href="#">Level 2 Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="level-2-item"><a href="#">Level 2 Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="level-2-item">
          <a href="#">Level 2 Item 3 with Sub-Items</a>
          <ul class="level-3-menu">
            <li class="level-3-item"><a href="#">Level 3 Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="level-3-item"><a href="#">Level 3 Item 2 longer</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1-item">
      <a href="#">Level 1 Item 2</a>
      <ul class="level-2-menu">
        <li class="level-2-item"><a href="#">Level 2 Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="level-2-item"><a href="#">Level 2 Item 2 longer</a></li>
      </ul>      
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cssmenu {
  background-color: white;
}
.cssmenu ul {
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.cssmenu li {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.cssmenu li:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.cssmenu li a {
  padding: 20px;
}

.level-1-menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.level-1-item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.level-2-menu,
.level-3-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.level-1-item:hover .level-2-menu,
.level-2-item:hover .level-3-menu {
  display: block;
}

.level-2-menu {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.level-3-menu {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.level-2-item {
  position: relative;
}

.level-2-item::after,
.level-3-item::after {
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.level-2-item:first-child::after,
.level-3-item:first-child::after {
  top: -30px;
}

.level-2-item:last-child::after,
.level-3-item:last-child::after {
  bottom: -30px;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion has been just what I needed! It's brought up a new question. What if I wanted to limit the height of level-3-menu to something like 250px, and add a scroll bar? If I do so currently the red border is within the scrolled area, not outside of it like I need it to be. My biggest issue is for this menu I only have so much screen real estate and if I list all the sub links it would run off the page so having a scroll bar is essential.

Comment: @gwb1231 I've added a new jsFiddle with modified code to solve that problem. Now you can set the height of the level 3 menu. The only problem is that the border of the level 3 menu covers the bottom right corner of the level 2 menu, including the previous item, in this case Level 2 Item 2.